# Select rows based on condition on rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a pandas dataframe that I want to clean.Here is an example:

| IDBILL | IDBUYER | BILL | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 768787 | 45 | 1897-07-24 |
| 002 | 768787 | 30 | 1897-07-24 |
| 005 | 786545 | 45 | 1897-08-19 |
| 008 | 657676 | 89 | 1989-09-23 |
| 009 | 657676 | 42 | 1989-09-23 |
| 010 | 657676 | 18 | 1989-09-23 |
| 012 | 657676 | 51 | 1990-03-10 |
| 016 | 892354 | 73 | 1990-03-10 |
| 018 | 892354 | 48 | 1765-02-14 |

I want to delete the highest bills(and keep the lowest when the bills are made on the same day, by the same IDBUYER, and whose bills IDs follow each other.
To get this:

| IDBILL | IDBUYER | BILL | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | 768787 | 30 | 1897-07-24 |
| 005 | 786545 | 45 | 1897-08-19 |
| 010 | 657676 | 18 | 1989-09-23 |
| 012 | 657676 | 51 | 1990-03-10 |
| 016 | 892354 | 73 | 1990-03-10 |
| 018 | 892354 | 48 | 1765-02-14 |

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Firstly convert **'DATE'** column into datetime dtype by using `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
```

Try with `groupby()` method:

```
result=df.groupby(['IDBUYER',df['DATE'].dt.day],as_index=False)[['IDBILL','BILL','DATE']].min()
```

**OR**

```
result=df.groupby(['DATE', 'IDBUYER'], sort=False)[['IDBILL','BILL']].min().reset_index()
```

Output of `result`:

```
    IDBUYER     IDBILL  BILL    DATE
0   657676      12      51      1990-03-10
1   657676      8       18      1989-09-23
2   768787      1       30      1897-07-24
3   786545      5       45      1897-08-19
4   892354      16      73      1990-03-10
5   892354      18      48      1765-02-14
```

Comment: Easiest solution if  he just wants the min values, but I am not sure that solves the: **and whose bills IDs follow each other** part, if that is actually relevant for the solution.

Comment: @Anurag Dabas- We might not required a new column `DAY`..... `df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df = df.groupby(['DATE', 'IDBUYER'], sort=False)[['IDBILL','BILL']].min().reset_index()`

Comment: @Uts Yup you are right so I fixed it...Thnx for noticing **:)**

Comment: Same comment as @Andreas, it works but isn't there a way to control the need for IDBILLs to follow each other in order to delete one?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this line `there a way to control the need for IDBILLs to follow each other in order to delete one`?pls explain

Comment: In my example 001 and 002 follow each other, but for example if we replace the IDBILL of 002 with 003, we should not delete 001 because 001 and 003 do not follow each other. But thanks anyway, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @ascha if they not follow each other and should not be deleted why are they missing in your sample output data?

Comment: @ascha maybe ask another question regarding this....as I also want to know how It can be done....lol

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to keep only min values of the lowest entry which is a follow-upof the idbill:

```
df['follow_up'] = df['IDBILL'].ne(df['IDBILL'].shift()+1).cumsum()

m = df.groupby(['IDBUYER', 'follow_up', df['DATE']])['BILL'].idxmin()
df.loc[sorted(m)]

#    IDBILL  IDBUYER  BILL        DATE  follow_up
# 1       2   768787    30  1897-07-24          1
# 2       5   786545    45  1897-08-19          2
# 5      10   657676    18  1989-09-23          3
# 6      12   657676    51  1990-03-10          4
# 7      16   892354    73  1990-03-10          5
# 8      18   892354    48  1765-02-14          6
```